# webhook not receiving incoming messages from kik

Tags: webhooks, kik

I am developing a chatbot on the kik platform. I made sure all the parameters are configured correctly, specifically the chatbot name, kik-api key, and the webhook. However, sometime, the webhook stops receiving any incoming message from the chatbot on kik even without changing  anything else, sometimes, it just drops dead!

In the beginning and whenever I used to face this problem, I was able to overcome it by changing kik-api key. Now, even after changing the kik-api key, the webhook still can’t receive messages. I am not getting any errors on my server. Is there any way I can troubleshoot this and prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It became alive without really changing anything in the code. I just restarted the application a couple times.